# Cannot download files on WSL "Permission Denied" "Cannot write to [...] (Success)"

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, adb

Im trying to install Bazelisk on WSL but when I try to download it typing: "wget [https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/releases/download/v1.15.0/bazelisk-linux-amd64"](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/releases/download/v1.15.0/bazelisk-linux-amd64%22) a message shows up saying "Permission Denied".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRaHs.png)

I'm following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65656165/how-do-you-install-bazel-using-bazelisk

And following this guide to install Mediapipe: https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/install.html#installing-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl

Comment: I can see no reason to be doing this in the /mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/ directory - change to your WSL user's home directory using `cd` and try the command again

Comment: @steeldriver Agreed that it is the problem, but as for "no reason", the problem is that often WSL defaults to it, if the Windows parent process was called from that directory (and many do default to it for one reason or another).  So it's an easy, honest mistake to make ... ;-)

Comment: And welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  As a heads-up, we ask that you don't post text as images.  See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933) for many reasons why. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @steeldriver mentioned in the comments, this is due to the fact that you are in the Windows System32 directory when you are attempting the download.

```
/mnt/c/Windows/System32
```

maps to the Windows directory:

```
C:\Windows\System32
```

This is *always* a restricted directory on Windows, to avoid system corruption and potential malware, and you would be restricted from downloading to that directory from *any* Windows application as your default user.

It's recommend that you use the virtual ext4 filesystem that WSL2 provides, which includes your home directory.  Simply:

```
cd ~
# or just cd without any arguments
```

... to return to your *Ubuntu* home directory, where you will have permission to download.

*Side-note:*  When starting WSL, the "default" directory is determined by the parent process, which may be the Windows System32 directory in some cases.  If you start WSL with `wsl ~`, then it will always default to your home directory instead.